# Number in database is not updated using RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, redbean

Using RedBaeanPHP, I want the page to be updated and add + 1 to the "view".
Please help me, I don't understand it very well.

```
$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
$posts = R::load('posts', $post_id);

if (isset($_SESSION['recent_posts'])) {
    R::exec('UPDATE posts SET view = "view" + 1 WHERE id = $posts["id"]');
};
```

When a page is refreshed, it is not added to the database.

Comment: The reason why your code is not working is the fact that variables are not expanded when they occur in single quoted strings (c.f.: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks, already solved the problem

```
$id = $posts['id'];
$view = "UPDATE `posts` SET `view` = `view` + 1 WHERE `id`= $id";
R::exec($view);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already loaded the rquested post from the database (by doing `$posts = R::load('posts', $post_id);`) you could  use the `store` method instead of `R::exec...`. So just use `$posts->view++;` and `R::store($posts);`